# Фокусировка инпута

Tags: jquery, form

Подскажите, как сделать при помощи jQuery вот такую вещь: есть `input text`, необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на него, под ним появлялась кнопка и прочие элементы формы. При нажатии же на пустое поле форма опять сворачивалась и показывался только `input text`. Такое используется при публикации сообщений на стене Вконтакте и похожих социальных сетях. Подкиньте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь туториал на эту тему или пример. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: у ВАС больше половины не принятых ответов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, думаю как показать форму понятно. Вешаем обработчик на фокус или клик и отображаем нужные элементы:

```
$('#id_поля').focus(function () {
  $('#блок_который_нужно_показать').show();
}
```

Скрывать же его нужно если клик произошел ВНЕ области блока, который мы показываем. Решение я нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it) :

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

что означает следующее - если клик был по области, которая НЕ является нашим блоком или не содержится в нем, то скрыть блок.

Comment: и обычный $('#id_поля').blur( должен срабатывать если кликнуть не на инпуте

Comment: ну да, а как использовать форму, которую показали с помощью `focus`?